# Jquery. Получить текст из конкретного елемента

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```
 <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Modified</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      <tr class="block-row">
         <th scope="row">1</th>
         <td class="schemas-name">Name</td>
         <td>Date</td>
         <td>
           <a class="read-link" href="" onclick="deleteSchema()">Delete</a>
         </td>
     </tr>
     
     <tr class="block-row">
         <th scope="row">1</th>
         <td class="schemas-name">Alex</td>
         <td>Dates</td>
         <td>
           <a class="read-link" href="" onclick="deleteSchema()">Delete</a>
         </td>
     </tr>
     
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Нужно получить текст из `<td class="schemas-name"></td>`

```
function deleteSchema(){
    console.log($(this).parents('.block-row').children('.schemas-name').text())
}
```

Выдает " " вместо текста. Помогите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем коде `this` внутри `deleteSchema` - это `window`.

```
<a class="read-link" href="" onclick="deleteSchema(this)">Delete</a>

function deleteSchema(el) {
  console.log($(el).closest('.block-row').find('.schemas-name').text());
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Максим Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.